# MSSQL int increment by one: increments by 2 instead of by 1

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, increment

I am puzzled, my column value is always incremented by 2 instead of 1.

On login failure, the following query is executed:

```
$sql_string = <<<SQL    
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM failed_logins_user WHERE user_id = $user_id))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO failed_logins_user (user_id, attempts_count)
    VALUES ($user_id, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE failed_logins_user
    SET attempts_count = attempts_count + 1
    WHERE user_id = $user_id
END
SQL;
```

Expected:

- On first failed attempt, the row is created, with attempts_count == 1
- On second failed attempt, the row is updated, with attempts_count == 2

Actual:

- On first failed attempt, the row is created, with attempts_count == **2**
- On second failed attempt, the row is updated, with attempts_count == **4**

Can anybody see, where my mistake is? Did I get the IF/ELSE wrong?
(*user_id is primary key, btw*)

(PS: I use parameter binding for $user_id - I just simplified this part of the query.)

Comment: Sounds like either (a) you're unintentionally running the query twice (we'd need to see the rest of the PHP code to figure that out) or (b) you might have a trigger which is updating the values.

Comment: Please post not only the query but also the relevant PHP code. You are almost certainly calling this query twice, either due to an error in the PHP or because you are processing two requests (perhaps a failure and also a redirect) on a failed login.

Comment: You say that @jasie, but the behaviour you're getting suggests not. Provide the code anyway so that we *can* eliminate that reason.

Comment: Thanks, commenters. I thought I had a mistake in my query. I could add the php code, but, in this case, though, this would be a page reload issue or sth like that - no use to post all that code.

Comment: @jasie Silly question, but do you have 2 rows with same user_id ?

Comment: No I don't @vivek_23. user_id is primary key.

Comment: @jasie Ok, check for triggers in your table. What happens if you do a normal insert? Do it directly in your database. Does this time too `attempts_count` comes as `2`?

Comment: Solved! Commenters were right: if I RELOAD the page, the count is correctly incremented by 1, if I use the LOGIN BUTTON, the query is executed twice. Would be anybody believe me, that I did NOT write the PHP code (except the func with the query)? WTF... Thanks @Nick and Ed Cottrell

Comment: @EdCottrell Why is my question off-topic? It is about programming and SO was able to help me with this issue.

Comment: @jasie That close reason is a little misleading, unfortunately. Your question was on-topic. But, you’ve solved the problem, and the reason for the error is in code that’s not part of your post. In those situations, (1) you’ve gotten help (yay!), (2) there’s nothing else that the community can do constructively, and (3) the question is unlikely to help other people going forward. We put it on hold mostly to let other users know that it doesn’t need additional answers.

Comment: @EdCottrell I understand, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something more like this.

First, start with a unique index on `failed_logins_user`:

```
create unique index unq_failed_logins_user_user_id on failed_logins_user(user_id);
```

Then try the update first and check if anything is updated:

```
DECLARE @rc INT;

UPDATE failed_logins_user
    SET attempts_count = attempts_count + 1
    WHERE user_id = @user_id;  -- pass this value in as a parameter!

SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO failed_logins_user (user_id, attempts_count)
        VALUES (@user_id, 1);  -- pass this value in as a parameter!
END;
```

All that said, I would keep each failed login as a separate row in `failed_logins_user`.  In particular, I would want the date/time of the failure and perhaps the device/IP address of the user.

Comment: Thanks. I do have the datetime as third colum in my table, I just ommited it from the code to keep it simple. But your suggestion is good - not to use count but to add every failed login attempt as row. BUT instead of one row there might be added up to 10 or 20 rows for each user, so it is a bit greedy. I wonder: is counting rows faster that extracting the value from attempts_count colum?

Comment: @jasie . . . Counting rows is obviously going to be more time consuming, even with the correct indexes.  The point is that details about each failed login might be relevant.